# WORDPRESS: how to get Row count of SELECT Field

Tags: wordpress, rowcount

Below is the my code , regardless of what code i put , i always get the tot post count and not individual country count , please help in replacing the pseudo code with the logic of code 
I have an custom post type field = Events 
Under events i have Select field with 2 values "INDIA' and "US"
I am trying to get the count of posts posted by single user in both of this countries ..

```
    <?php 

// args
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'event',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'       => 'location',
        'value'     => 'INDIA',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'location',
        'value'     => 'US',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
      )
   )
);


// query
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 ?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

<?
   ******************************************
  //Add code here to count the posts  of INDIA and US 
  Psuedo code is as shown below 
 iF meta.LOCATION ="INDIA"
  get row count (Locaton-->india)
 endif
iF meta.LOCATION ="US"
  get row count (Locaton-->india)
endif
***********************************

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```